# What could be wrong with this virtual host file in Apache?

Tags: django, apache, virtualhost

I am trying to route an application to a sub route on an internal server, using Gunicorn with my Django app. My virtual host file looks like this:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 172.16.1.81
        <Location "/mycustomapp">
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9090
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9090
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I navigate to 172.16.1.81/mycustomapp , I keep getting a 404 not found error when trying to navigate to the application on that route. Is there something else I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your app is running on port `9090` and not on `3000` (which is the default Django port)?

Comment: Yes. Using Gunicorn, I bind it to listen on port 9090.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. For anyone running into this type of problem in the future, the solution lies in using the `ServerPath` directive inside your VirtualHost configuration. So for example, if you wanted to have an application be served at 172.15.1.20/app1 and another application served at 172.15.1.20/app2 (via port forwarding to a process listening on a port) the virtual host configuration would like the following:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib64/apache2/mod_proxy_http.so
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 172.15.1.20

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /app1 http://127.0.0.1:9090
    ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://127.0.0.1:9090

    ProxyPass /app2 http://127.0.0.1:9080
    ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://127.0.0.1:9080

</VirtualHost>
```